# In JPA, how can you know if a Persistance Exception was caused by a specific database trigger?

Tags: java, sqlite, exception, jpa, triggers

Suppose i have two triggers and both raise two different errors in the database.
When i try to insert a new entity and catch the persistance exception, how can i discriminate between those two errors? I mean something like this:

```java
try {

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    entityManager.persist(entity);

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

} catch (EntityExistsException exception) {

    //...

} catch (PersistenceException exception) {

    if(ERROR_FROM_TRIGGER_ONE) {
        //do something about it
    } else if(ERROR_FROM_TRIGGER_TWO) {
        //do something about it
    }
}
```

Comment: and you've looked at the "cause" exception of the persistence exception?

Comment: I tried, but getting the cause of the exception don´t tell me if the error comes from one place or another, and i need to make different things based on the type of error that can came from one trigger or another.

Comment: Your trigger will simply send some SQLException. A JPA implementation will simply wrap whatever your trigger causes. That's all there is

Comment: Ok, in that case i can do nothing. I would like to raise more complex exceptions through the SQLite triggers, but i don´t think the raise function would let me do that. And when i catch the exceptions in JPA i always catch them with error code 0. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA uses JDBC API as low level and from side of jdbc driver there is no difference between error in incorrect query syntax or broken trigger. So generally you cant implement such check.

But some database vendors (Oracle for example) provide unique error number in message when exception occurs, which can be used to identify real problem such as broken trigger.

Comment: Im using SQLite, so i doubt i can do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the first error thrown a `EJBTransactionRollBack`? If not just catch a general error, siphon down to the root cause and then handle it appropriately

```
catch (Exception e) {
   while(e.getCause() != null) {
      e = e.getCause();
   }
   if(e instanceof PersistenceException) {
      //do something
   } else if (e instanceof EntityExistsException) {
     //do something else 
   }
}
```